# Prolog interpreter

Tags: prolog, interpreter

I have to 'code' something like Eliza.pl , I don't know how to start.
I found that link: 
http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/WSV/teaching/projekte/eliza.pl
it is what I need to 'code' , but i don't want to step against law, so I want do it by myself.

How to start that work? what to start from?

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean by "doing interpreter in Prolog"?  Are you going to use a Prolog interpreter, write one, or implement an interpreter in Prolog?  Your link is to an Eliza program in Prolog; are you trying to write Eliza in Prolog?  What do you mean by "steps to do":  things that you should do, or Prolog statements?

Comment: by doing interpreter: Trying to write Eliza;
steps to do: things that I should do;

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of Eliza is nicely explained in the following book:

```
 An Introduction to Language Processing with Perl and Prolog
 Pierre M. Nugues
 http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Language-Processing-Perl-Prolog/dp/3642064051
 Section 9: Partial Parsing, Section 9.2.1: ELIZA
```

You also find working Prolog code examples. But the code makes use
of Definite Clause Grammars (DCG) and of course it makes use of Prolog.

So before going to work with the book, you should probably take a 
basic course of Prolog that covers also some DCG.

Best Regards